# htaccess Redirecting With Subdirectory as a Variable

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

What I'm trying to do is redirect example.com/author/authorname/ to example.com/author/authorname/page/1/ for the pagination to work more efficiently at the initial load of a page.

Currently I got

```
RedirectMatch /example/author/(.*) http://localhost:8888/example/author/(.*)/page/1/
```

I was trying to use a wildcard variable but that doesn't seem to work. In the first place where the (.*) is I would need to store that value as a variable and use that exact same name in the similar place in the redirection location.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch ^/example/author/([^/]+)/?$ /example/author/$1/page/1
```

or if you already have mod_rewrite rules, you should probably stick to that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example/author/([^/]+)/?$ /example/author/$1/page/1 [L,R]
```